# Stripe vs mastercard?

Tags: stripe-payments, mastercard

why do developers use Stripe not Master-card API or Visa API while stripe charges money more. i checked and found out Master-card and Visa have their own API's , i guess there's something there i don't understand? probably i live in egypt, which global service should i use to integrate in my PHP websites while Stripe is not available in egypt?

```
sjsonp1389885476573({
  "error": {
    "message": "Your card was declined.",
    "type": "card_error",
    "code": "card_declined"
  }
}
, 402)
```

Thank you

Comment: Hi Mohamed, Did you manage to choose a payment gateway in Egypt. I am interested to know which option you chose

Comment: I chose https://www.weaccept.co , they are kinda cool

Comment: Thanks are they located in egypt

Comment: yw, not really sure, but they provide egyption phone numbers on their facebook page that you can check and call them, and also a trusted gateway is https://www.payfort.com , they are located in KSA, but you'll need to provide your Commercial Register and some other info.. hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the primary reason why developers use payment gateways such as stripe and not separate APIs for master, visa, maestro etc. as you need to do development and testing individually for these APIs along with monitoring any changes that happen with them.

Stripe on the other hand provides an API layer over all these APIs and simplify them so that businesses don't have to worry about integrating the separate APIs.

The list of payment gateways available in Egypt currently includes :

- 2Checkout
- BitPay
- Coinbase
- GoCoin
- Mastercard Payment Gateway Services
- NETbilling
- PayFort
- PayPal Express Checkout
- Paystack

Also, the integration time is very less with these payment gateways as compared to the APIs of payment solutions such as master, visa, maestro, etc. as these gateways provides single API which supports payment options for all major payment solutions.

Hope this helps!